# Fastest way to add a column in numpy array with a specific value?

Tags: python, numpy

This is most likely a duplicate; apologies as I couldn't find the answer. I have a (3000, 3) array and I want to make a (3000, 4) array with the last column being a specific value. I can do a very simple `np.insert(x, 1, val, axis=1)` to insert the value before column 1, but I can't add it to the last column with np.insert(). I can do `np.repeat(val, np.shape(x)[0])` or using `np.hstack()` but they require creating an array first of the same length as the original array (which varies) and a bit clunky (maybe this is the only way), and I'm guessing there is a better way if I am only concerned with one value I want to append.

Is there anything better than
`np.concatenate((x, np.repeat(val, np.shape(x)[0])[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)`?

Comment: I would normally go for the `np.hstack` method. It wouldn't really require any extra memory. But may I ask, if the value is the same for every row, why do you need this column in the array at all?

Comment: I just have other arrays with different values for the last column (computed in different places) to then combine afterwards so it's just easier to to have this procedure at this particular step.

Comment: I see. If you do want an array with shape `(3000, 4)`, there is no way around allocating the memory for that extra column. So I'd suggest to just go with `np.hstack`.

Comment: What about  np.c_[z,np.ones_like(z[:,0])*val] ? I don't know if it's "better" but it's slightly more concise IMO

Comment: Copy the array to a (3000,4), and the fill value to the last column .

Answer (score 2):

You can allocate a larger array, copy old values from x and fill the last column with a scalar with a little help of broadcasting

```
y=np.empty_like(x, shape=(3000,4))
y[:,:-1]=x
y[:,-1]=your_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using np.c_ and np.ones_like to cut out some verbosity, but the solution is similar to your suggestion

```
x=np.c_[x,val*np.ones_like(x[:,0])]
```

It doesn't require allocating memory for a new matrix.